# Order of integration does matter

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

We have equal partial derivatives in 3d coordinates ( continuous partial derivatives and smoothness assumed) independent of order e.g. in Monge form $z=f(x,y)$

$$\frac{\partial ^2 z }{\partial x \,\partial y}= \frac{\partial ^2 z }{\partial y \,\partial x}$$

Is this true for full derivatives including arbitrary functionally dependent variables in general?

I guess not...

$$\dfrac{d^3 y}{d z \cdot ds \cdot dx},\; \dfrac{d^3 y}{d s \cdot dx \cdot dz} ,\;\dfrac{d^3 y}{d x \cdot dz\cdot ds}; $$

such higher order full derivatives cannot all be equal or be the same scalars..  cannot follow such cycling indifferent pattern set by partial derivative precedents... they have different meanings...

If they are equal then what is the ***Order rule*** while integrating ODEs?

Background to my question is a particular example:

When 2D circle coordinates $(x,y)$ making up the arc $s, \ ( ds^2=dx^2+dy^2, \text{slope}= \phi) $ are multi-variably related we have constant curvature $ \kappa$  ode for a Circle in a particular example:

$$ \frac{d ^2 y }{d x \;ds} = 1, \text{ or }  \frac{\frac{d ^2 y }{dx^2}}{\left({1+\left (\frac {dy}{dx}\right)^2}\right)^{3/2}} =1 \tag 1 $$

However

$$ \frac{d ^2 y }{ds\;dx} =1,\text{ or }  \frac{\frac{d ^2 y }{dx^2}}{\left({1+\left (\frac {dy}{dx}\right)^2}\right)^{1/2}} =1 \tag 2 $$

does not even represent a Circle, as a different magenta curve below (same tangent x-axis at start ) is found by numerical integration:

[image]

Analytically the second curve for zero slope origin start is found to be:

$$ y= \cosh x -1 $$

Using differentials their intrinsic odes that are  different before and after swap are:

$$ \frac{d^2 y }{dx ds}=\frac{d \sin \phi }{dx}=\cos \phi \cdot \kappa \cdot \sec \phi = \kappa =1, $$

$$ \frac{d^2 y }{ds dx}=   \frac{d \tan \phi }{ds} = \sec^2 \phi \cdot \kappa =1. $$

Comment: It is [true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2718864) for all sufficiently smooth coordinates. $s $ defined in your example is not a general 2d- coordinate. It depends on the choice of a specific curve.

Comment: Does the link specify that (x,y) cannot be *any* dependent variables but can *only* be surface coordinates?

Comment: You should specify what meaning have the variables $x,y$ in the expression $z(x,y)$. Usual meaning is that the function $z$ is a map $\mathbb R^2\mapsto\mathbb R$ and can be visualized as a two-dimensional surface. What is the meaning of $z,x,y,(s)$ in your interpretation?

Comment: Standard $z=f(x,y)$  Monge form of 2D surface, with Pythagorean metric $ ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 $.

Comment: The coordinates are $x,y$. $s$ is not a coordinate.

Comment: My question does not premise on their being coordinates.

Comment: After you repeatedly changing  the question it is hard to say what it exactly about.

Comment: No change in the question.. I am trying to explain the question.

Comment: What you're writing just makes no sense. You know better than this.

Comment: Under usual definitions the integration of $$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}=1$$ results in $$z(x,y)=xy+f(x)+g(y)$$ independent of the integration order. If you arbitrarily change the definitions you may obtain an arbitrary result.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Please answer or comment what in my question in particular  makes no sense. I would edit to improve the question.